Azure devops pipeline: how to dynamically match a variable defined under variable group
I have a bash script in my ADO yaml pipeline that unzips a given set of files, some of these files are password protected. I have created a variable group and referenced it in my pipeline & defined the name of each password protected file as a key and their password as a secret value.
I would like to loop of over the target files and and for each file if there is a matching key or if its value is not empty then get the password defined under variable group. I have tried a few things but unfortunately no luck yet.
Variable group:
Key         Value
test.zip    ****  ->(testValue)

Pipeline:
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      file_dir="some_dir"
    
    
      if [ -d "$file_dir" ]; then
        echo "Listing files in $file_dir:"
      
        for file in "$file_dir"/*; do
          if [ -f "$file" ]; then
            build_var="$""("$file")"
            echo $build_var -> # prints $(test.zip)
            # Goal
            unzip -P "$(build_var)" test.zip -d .
            
          fi
        done
      fi

Since the pipeline processes lots of different files everyday I'm trying to find a way to not have to hardcode things as much as possible.
Is this possible?

For the password variable set in variable group, they should be set as secret variables, right?

Yes thats correct

Got it. Let me do some tests and check this requirement further.

Thanks alot, I’ve updated the sample script

I am afraid that the requirement can not be achieved in single pipeline if you want to avoid hardcoding the filenames. I have shared a solution in the answer to avoid hardcoding, you can refer it.

Thanks alot Kevin, the solution you provided works. however I trying to explore to see if there is away to achieve this in a single pipeline, do you think it would be possible to achieve this in a multi stage, template format pipeline where I can use task.setvariable and assign the array of the file names as its value then pass it to next stage/template using parameters?

I am afraid that your idea cannot be achieved. The variable set in pipeline(task.setvariable)can not be passed to parameters in a single pipeline. This is the reason why I split the pipeline into two. Since the variable is the secret variable in variable group, it is not possible to directly get the value via nested variable. So the suggested method is splitting one pipeline into two.

Based on your description, you need to get the secret variable value in variable group based on the file name variable.
The secret variable will not be set in the Pipeline environment variable, so when you use the nested variable("$""("$file")") in bash script, it will not read the correct secret variable.
Since you doesn't want to hardcode the files in Pipeline, I afraid that you are not able to achieve the requirement in the single pipeline.
To meet your requirement, I suggest that you can split the pipelines into two. One is used to collect the file names(save to array) and trigger the other pipeline with the required array. The other pipeline is used to loop the file names and get the related secret password in variable group.
Here is an example:
variable Group:
file1.zip  ***
file2.zip  ***

Pipeline One:
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      file_dir="file_pat"
      file_array=()
    
      if [ -d "$file_dir" ]; then
        echo "Listing files in $file_dir:"
      
        for file in "$file_dir"/*; do
           file_array+=$(basename $file,)
        done
      fi      
      echo $file_array

      az pipelines run --id {PipelintwoID} --organization $(System.CollectionUri) --project {YourProjectname} --parameters filenames="[$file_array]"
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(PAT)

Pipeline Two: We can use format: $(${{filename}}) to get the secret variable in Variable Group
parameters:
- name: filenames
  type: object
  default: []
variables:
- group: filePass

steps:
- ${{ each filename in parameters.filenames }}:
  - bash: |
      echo ${{filename}}
    
      if [ -z "$(${{filename}})" ]
      then
        #variablevalue is null
            unzip  test.zip -d . 
      else
        #variablevalue is not null
            unzip -P "$(${{filename}})" test.zip -d .
      fi

Result: It will loop all file names in the array and run related commands in different tasks.

Here is the doc related to Azure DevOps CLI trigger Pipeline: az pipelines run

You can dynamically access a pipeline variable in at least 2 different ways:

Using Recursive expansion
Using a parameter

Using recursive expansion
Variables referenced using $( ) syntax are recursively expanded:
variables:
  myInner: someValue
  myOuter: $(myInner)

steps:
- script: echo $(myOuter)  # prints "someValue"
  displayName: Variable is $(myOuter)  # display name is "Variable is someValue"

Using parameters
Given that parameters will be evaluated at compile time, you can dynamically set the variable based on the parameter value using syntax $(${{ parameters.xxxxxx }}):
parameters:
  - name: filename
    type: string
    default: test.zip
    values:
      - test.zip
      - foobar.zip

trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  - group: 'group1' # contains variables test.zip and foobar.zip

  - name: selectedFile
    value: $(${{ parameters.filename }})

steps:
- checkout: none

- script: |
    echo "Selected file: $(selectedFile)"
  displayName: 'Print selected file value'

So regarding the above pipeline, if foobar.zip is selected then pipeline variable selectedFile will have the following value when it is compiled:
  - name: selectedFile
    value: $(foobar.zip)


thanks but I'm looking for a way to avoid hardcoding variables in pipeline every time since the file names change all the time

@flankers33 mine are just suggestions on how to use variables dynamically. Not knowing exactly your scenario, that's the best I can do. Now it's up to you to adapt the code to your scenario. Or maybe add more details to your question?

I know, thanks for your suggestions I’ve updated the sample script in my question
